# how to set this animation for the android banner anybody can know

Tags: android, animation, banner

[image]

this is banner  i know

```
viewpager.setPageTransformer(boolean reverseDrawingOrder, PageTransformer transformer) ;
```

But to the PageTransformer  i don't how do set

Answer (score 0):

yes i get by myself 
just like   get call back onTransform(View view, float position) 
set view.setTranslationX(position < 0 ?   0  :  -view.getWidth() * position/2);
this ok